# Simulation of Automotive Radiators

Tags: fluid-mechanics, automotive-engineering, simulation, cooling, heat-exchanger

I'm going to simulate an **automotive radiator** . The method called $\varepsilon$- NTU , suggests following steps to calculate the heat rejection,$Q$, of a heat exchanger:

1-calculate $U$(overall heat transfer coefficient)

2- calculate $NTU$

3- calculate $\varepsilon$ and finally calculate $Q(W)$.

My question is about calculation of $U$ in automotive radiators. We can neglect fouling and wall resistances and write:
$$
 \frac{1}{UA} = \frac{1}{\eta_aA_ah_a}+\frac{1}{A_wh_w}
$$
$U$: Overall heat transfer coefficient. 
$A$ : Air side or waterside area. 
$A_a$ : Air side heat transfer area
$A_w$: Waterside heat transfer Area 
$h$ : heat transfer coefficient
 $\eta_a$ air side surface efficiency.
I want to use *Shanoun & Webb* formula to calculate the first term of the above equation(Air thermal resistance). They propose following equation for **automotive radiators**:  $$ (\eta Ah)_a=(\eta_f Ah)_{l} +(\eta_f Ah)_{S1}+(\eta_f Ah)_{S2}+h_eA_e$$  You can find regions named *louvered(l)*,*S1*,*S2* and *e* in following image: [image]  This is image of a fin between *2* flat tubes.
**Question**:  *Shanoun and Webb* just enter areas relating to one fin in their equation. So when we want to calculate $UA$, we account total surface of water$A_w$ but just a small surface of air side$A_a$. It makes the answer wrong. How can we use this formula to calculate $UA$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should multiply the No. of fins to the right-hand-side statement. So we have:
$$(\eta hA)_a=No.of fins \times( (\eta_fhA)_l+(\eta_fhA)_{S1}+(\eta_fhA)_{S2}+h_eA_e)$$

Comment: Is this an answer or is it supposed to be added to the question?

Comment: It is the answer.